# DocPad plugin: odd errors when testing, hangs when including in project

Tags: coffeescript, docpad

I'm trying to write a DocPad plugin to import MongoDB docs into the DocPad database for use in a static website. The source code is at https://github.com/nfriedly/docpad-plugin-mongodb and it's based on https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-tumblr

When I run `cake test`, I get this output:

```
cake compile
cake install
npm install (for app)
npm install (for test)
npm install (for docpad tests)
coffee compile
npm test

> docpad-plugin-mongodb@2.0.0 test c:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\docpad-plugin-mongodb
> npm run prepare_test_db && node ./out/mongodb.test.js


> docpad-plugin-mongodb@2.0.0 prepare_test_db c:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\docpad-plugin-mongodb
> mongo test/prepare_database.mongo.js

MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: test
connecting to: docpad_plugin_mongodb_test
mongodb
mongodb > create
notice: If everyone who saw this message donated $1/week, maintaining DocPad would become sustainable: http://docpad.org/donate
error: An error occured:
Error: Didn't place the skeleton as the desired structure already exists
  at c:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\docpad-plugin-mongodb\node_modules\docpad\out\lib\docpad.js:4107:17
  at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:168:19)
error: To report the above error, follow the guide at: http://docpad.org/bug-report
mongodb > create OK
mongodb > load plugin mongodb
mongodb > load plugin mongodb OK
mongodb > generate
mongodb > generate > action
warning: You have multiple files being written to c:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\docpad-plugin-mongodb\test\out\testData\1.json, they are:
  - testData/1.json:c7
  - testData/1.json:c5
  Rename one of them to avoid an over-write

FAILURE: 2/3 tests ran successfully; 0 failed, 1 incomplete, 0 errors

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0

c:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\docpad-plugin-mongodb\Cakefile:99
      throw err;
            ^
Error: Process exited with error status code
  at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\docpad-plugin-mongodb\Cakefile:88:15)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

And, when I include the module in my project, it just hangs after this:

```
$ docpad run
info: Welcome to DocPad v6.69.1 (local installation: c:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\watson-developer-cloud\node_modules\docpad
notice: If everyone who saw this message donated $1/week, maintaining DocPad would become sustainable: http://docp
info: Contribute: http://docpad.org/docs/contribute
info: Plugins: eco, mongodb
info: Environment: development
info: DocPad listening to http://0.0.0.0:9778/ on directory c:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\watson-developer-cloud\out
```

(And if I visit localhost:9778, it just hangs and never loads a page)

It seems like it only displays logs from plugins after the first pass is complete, so I started adding `throw` statements to see what it was doing. It seems that it imports things from mongo successfully, and it creates the document, but when the plugin calls [`document.action 'load', (err) ->`](https://github.com/nfriedly/docpad-plugin-mongodb/blob/ea5a725cf5d2651318f0f949a121039218fbaea5/src/mongodb.plugin.coffee#L88), that callback is never fired.

Can anyone provide some guidance on what I'm messing up and how to get things working smoothly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The TaskGroup library (apparently) once had a `.once('complete', callback)` event that no longer works. Switching it to `.done(callback)` (and fixing a couple of other small bugs) got me working now.

It still gives me the "Error: Didn't place the skeleton as the desired structure already exists" but the tests all pass now, so I'll call it a win.